# How to receive JSON in a POST request in CherryPy?

Tags: json, post, cherrypy

How to receive JSON from POST requests in CherryPy?

I've been to [this page](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/jsontools.html), and though it does a good job explaining the API, its parameters, and what it does; I can't seem to figure out how to use them to parse the incoming JSON into an object.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import cherrypy
import json

from web.models.card import card
from web.models.session import getSession
from web.controllers.error import formatEx, handle_error

class CardRequestHandler(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def update(self, **jsonText):
        db = getSession()
        result = {"operation" : "update", "result" : "success" }
        try:
            u = json.loads(jsonText)
            c = db.query(card).filter(card.id == u.id)
            c.name = u.name
            c.content = u.content
            rzSession.commit()
        except:
            result["result"] = { "exception" : formatEx() }
        return json.dumps(result)
```

And, here's my jquery call to make the post

```
function Update(el){
    el = jq(el); // makes sure that this is a jquery object

    var pc = el.parent().parent();
    pc = ToJSON(pc);

    //$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset : "utf-8" });
    $.post( "http://localhost/wsgi/raspberry/card/update", pc,
            function(data){
                alert("Hello Update Response: " + data);
            }, 
            "json");
}

function ToJSON(h){
    h = jq(h);
    return { 
        "id" : h.attr("id"), 
        "name" : h.get(0).innerText, 
        "content" : h.find(".Content").get(0).innerText
    };
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Working example:

```
import cherrypy
import simplejson

class Root(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def update(self):
        cl = cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length']
        rawbody = cherrypy.request.body.read(int(cl))
        body = simplejson.loads(rawbody)
        # do_something_with(body)
        return "Updated %r." % (body,)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function Update() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "update",
      contentType: "application/json",
      processData: false,
      data: $('#updatebox').val(),
      success: function(data) {alert(data);},
      dataType: "text"
    });
}
</script>
<body>
<input type='textbox' id='updatebox' value='{}' size='20' />
<input type='submit' value='Update' onClick='Update(); return false' />
</body>
</html>
"""

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

The doc you linked to describes a couple of CherryPy Tools that are new in version 3.2. The `json_in` tool basically does the above, with some more rigor, and using the new body processing API in 3.2.

One important thing to note is that jQuery's `post` function doesn't seem to be able to send JSON (only receive it). The `dataType` argument specifies the type of data you expect the XmlHTTPRequest to *receive*, not the type it will send, and there doesn't seem to be an argument available for you to specify the type you want to send. Using `ajax()` instead allows you to specify that.

Answer (score 49):

## Python

```py
import cherrypy

class Root:

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def my_route(self):

        result = {"operation": "request", "result": "success"}

        input_json = cherrypy.request.json
        value = input_json["my_key"]

        # Responses are serialized to JSON (because of the json_out decorator)
        return result
```

## JavaScript

```js
//assuming that you're using jQuery

var myObject = { "my_key": "my_value" };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my_route",
    data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: `cherrypy.request` has no attribute `json`

Comment: @IAbstract check that you have the ```@cherrypy.tools.json_in()``` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `@cherrypy.tools.json_in()` way not very clean since it forces you to use `cherrypy.request.json`. Instead, the following decorator tries to mimic `GET` parameters.

The following helps this.

NOTE: This assumes you want to return JSON:

```
def uses_json(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media="application/json")
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        cherrypy.serving.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"

        kwargs = dict(kwargs)

        try:
            body = cherrypy.request.body.read()
            kwargs.update(json.loads(body))
        except TypeError:
            pass

        return json.dumps(func(*args, **kwargs)).encode('utf8')

    return wrapper
```

example:

```
 {"foo": "bar"}
```

get's translated into

```
 class Root(object): 
     ...
 
     @cherrypy.expose
     @uses_json
     def endpoint(self, foo):
         ....
```

Comment: This is actually quite an interesting approach. Could you explain a little about why you merge kwargs with json in response body? If everything is expected from json, what kind of parameters would come as kwargs?