# How is CherryPy providing the appropriate request context?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm a bit new to Python and I'm having trouble understanding some code from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753314/52551

The code is:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def update(self):
    cl = cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length']
    rawbody = cherrypy.request.body.read(int(cl))
    body = simplejson.loads(rawbody)
    # do_something_with(body)
    return "Updated %r." % (body,)
```

Like I said I'm a bit new at Python so my confusion is how `cherrypy.request` is able to provide the appropriate request context. If two clients make a request couldn't the first client's request information be overwritten by the second client's request information if there is a context switch somewhere inside the `update` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CherryPy uses a [threading.local](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#threading.local) object to manage the request and response context.