# How to receive text in a POST request in CherryPy?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cherrypy

[starting from this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753314/3387832)

It works perfectly only with numbers, how to change using a non-numeric data? (text)

Comment: What do you mean by "only with numbers"? It only works when you submit numbers? It shouldn't matter.

Comment: I mean that accepts character only if in quotes eg: "test" but not test