# AJAX - Override submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, function

I am trying to create login page but I stuck on sending data to Cherrypy as a JSON. Trying to override submit button because AJAX does not send any data when I am pressing the button.

**Old Code Deleted**

---

> @EDIT I have changed the code and now I am not sending any data to server (I assume that cuz there is nothing in console after pressing the button)

### **My .js**

```
$("#myForm").click(function(){
    var dataString = {};
    dataString.login = $("#login").val();
    dataString.password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

### **My .html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
      <form id="myForm" class="login-form">
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="login"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button form="myForm" type="submit">Login</button>
        <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### **Login Page (data not encrypted?)**

[PIC](http://prntscr.com/fiqn1s)

- Password in the link?

### **My Console (empty?)**

[PIC](http://prntscr.com/fiqnc5)

- No Login call

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: If I understand HTML correctly button should have proceeded all input above as a form request and send data to cherrypy engine. But it does not so I decided to override function on AJAX and then receive data I want but scripts seems not responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a post request (you have to handle post on server side as well):

```
type: 'POST',
```

Also put this inside your submit function:

```
var dataString = {};
dataString.login = $("#login").val();
dataString.password = $("#password").val();
```

So the code becomes :

```
<form id="myForm" class="login-form">
  <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="login"/>
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
  <button class="button_submit">login</button>
  <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
</form>

$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    var dataString = {};
    dataString.login = $("#login").val();
    dataString.password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
      contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So myForm here response to login-form in my html file am I right here?

Comment: @OskarGarczyński see my edit, is it clearer like this ? (I don't understand what you mean in your comment)

Comment: I've changed code's as you showed me but I am not receiving any output data after pressing the button in the console. How should I call them?

Comment: @OskarGarczyński Do you have a server running ? If so does it handles POST requests ?

Comment: yes I am using Cherrypy, I guess it does handle POST requests [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743769/how-to-receive-json-in-a-post-request-in-cherrypy)

Comment: @OskarGarczyński When the user press the button the data is sent to the server to the specific path '/login' as post request. Now how you handle that data is done on the server of course. You can check the data is sent via the network tab in google dev tools. How to process on the server side is out of scope of this question. But you can check that the code provided indeeds sends it to the server with the dev tools. The reason you are not seeing anything in the console is because your server doesn't answer anything.

Comment: anyway ur answers didn't help me anyway :/ [problem is somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499045/cherrypy-reciving-json-data-404-missing-parameters)

Comment: @OskarGarczyński I'd suggest following a simple tutorial. Your edit makes it pretty clear that you don't really know what you are doing but we can't do everything for you. If you have other questions please post another one as a new question

Answer (score 0):

Shift the `event.preventDefault()` to top. In your case the button was executing it's normal behaviour that is `submitting`, which need to be prevented to execute to ajax.

```
$('#button_submit').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    //rest of the code
  });

});
```

Comment: @RolandStarke thanks for pointing it. I have edited the answer

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: @charlietfl i am not sure why this is false?

Comment: Because it works the same whether it is at top or bottom or in the middle...assuming no exceptions are thrown before `preventDefault()` is reached. It is better practice to put it at top for that reason....but won't change behavior

Comment: also event won't be undefined as someone said earlier before you edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong referring to the button, see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)

Change:

```
<button class="button_submit">login</button>
```

to

```
<button id="button_submit">login</button>
```

Add name attribute to the input fields instead of id ( or use both if you prefer) and switch GET to POST to keep data hidden:

```
<input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="login"/>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
```

then fix the jQuery to :

```
$('#button_submit').on("click",function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
....
```

Comment: thanks a lot, was thinking about changing it to id. `<button type="submit">login</button>` is that correct now? or I need that ID to use ur ajax code

Comment: You need to use the same referring to manage the handler: - <button type="submit">login</button> needs $('#button_submit').click(function() {...}  - <button id="xxx">login</button> needs $('#xxx").click(function() {...}

Comment: There was a type error  $('#button_submit').on("click",function(e){...} not .on.(...

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be better to send a POST request as it is a bit more "hidden" request then just throwing the parameters with GET (POST sends data in the "background"). Also note, that if you want to correctly handle form submit and you're using jQuery, use `submit` event handler.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```